# parse foursquare json response after userless response in asp.net

Tags: c#, json.net, foursquare, sharpsquare

My client wants me to return a plain old delimited file or string from a foursquare query passing lat long and a query phrase. They wanted it in a web form and asp.net/ vb.net.  I have no idea why I just cash the checks.  I have the json response coming back and I can write that to a label on the form but I have not been able to parse the Foursquare json response.  I have the two textboxes on the form.  One for latlong and one for the query phrase.  On the button click I validate and call the following code.

```
Dim url As String = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id="
        url += txtClient_ID.Text
        url += "&client_secret="
        url += txtClient_Secret.Text
        url += "&v=20140212&ll="
        url += txtLatLong.Text
        url += "&query="
        url += txtQuery.Text
        url += "&radius="
        url += txtRadius.Text
        url += "&intent=browse"

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    request = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "GET"
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
    Dim jsonResponse As String = reader.ReadToEnd()`
```

Works very well and returns the raw json which I can then write to the form, etc..  My problem is getting this into human readable format.
I have imported the newtonsoft and sharpsquare libraries and am getting intellitype in VS for their classes but i can't seem to get the json to deserialized.  At this point I don't care if it's in a gridview or xml or some kind of tab delimited text.  I have tried

```
 Dim root As Object = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse)

    Dim venues As JArray = root("response")("venues")
    Dim firstVenue As JObject = venues(0)

    Dim whatever As New SharpSquare(txtClient_ID.Text, txtClient_Secret.Text)
    lblParsed.Text = whatever.SearchVenues(venues)
```

But get "Value of type newtonsoft.json.linq.array cannot be converted to system.collection.generic.dictionary(of string,string)"  Is Sharpsquare making the same webrequest as my previous call or am I just missing the boat on these dang nested arrays?  I can't find any docs on sharpsquare and the only code example is

```
Imports FourSquare.SharpSquare.Core
Imports FourSquare.SharpSquare.Entities
Dim clientId As String = "my client id"
    Dim clientSecret As String = "my client secret"
    Dim redirectUri As String = "REDIRECT_URI"
    Dim sharpSquare As New SharpSquare(clientId, clientSecret)
```

which does not error but what do I do now to access the actual results?  I have been at this for days and any help would be appreciated.